# Getting SharePoint list with curl has limits?

Tags: list, limitations, read

I have SharePoint list with more than 1000 items(ID's). 
I'm dumping list with *BASH* script to my server with *curl*:

`curl --ntlm -u $curl_account $SITE -o $output_file 2>/dev/null`

and I get only 1000 ID's to my *$output_file*. Is there are some limits or smth to do, that I could get all items?

Thanks for any info :)

Answer (score 1):

I dont see any limitation on data retrieving using curl. is it get only 1st 1000 items only?
Do you have any filter on your default view in list.

also check this blog, he used curl to print the list data.

http://blog.vgrem.com/tag/curl/

http://justinlee.sg/2011/01/05/crud-operations-on-microsoft-sharepoint-2010-odata-lists-with-curl/

Comment: Yes i'm getting only 1st 1000 items. And when I view at feed "$URL/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$listname" I can see only 1000 items. There is 1000 limitation at SharePoint. No filter's used.. just grouping.

I was advices to use Lists Web Services(SOAP). Working on that..

Answer (score 1):

add RowLimit=0

```
http://sharepoint/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&XMLDATA=1&RowLimit=0&List=%7BID1%7D&View=%7BID2%7D
```

Setting the row limit will override the default limit

Answer (score 0):

Try and do it in a loop, record the last id retrieved after each 1000, then add a filter to the call i.e. where ID > lastid. do this until the number of items retrieved is < 1000